# Camel routing based on object value

Tags: java, json, apache-camel

I have two simple Camel routes working for writing to a jms queue and reading from it. I am putting a serialized object to the queue. I am able to deserialize it and covert it to json successfully.

Route for writing:

```
from("direct:message").to("jms:myqueu")
```

My route for reading:

```
from("jms:myqueu")
.marshal()
.json(JsonLibrary.Gson).
.to("file://cc")
```

Now i want to check a field within the object and route based on that.**Also that field should not be part of the final json.**

Can i check the value within the object and route based on that( like write to different files?). I can add the annotation in the pojo to avoid the field in final json

I thought of converting object to json, and then sending to queue. Then i can use jsonpath for conditional routing. But then how can i omit a field from final json?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use content based routing to check any field in incoming object and do the routing based on that.

ref: http://camel.apache.org/content-based-router.html

To ignore a field during json marshalling , you can use @JsonIgnore - Jackson annotation.

Comment: Thanks. Thats what i had in mind. But i am confused on how to choose the field from the object. Camel deserializes the object and then i added the json conversion. So i need to check the field between them. Do i need to write a custom bean filter and invoke it?

Comment: No need. You can use camel simple language to invoke getter method of your bean.    ex: <simple>${body.getSomething} == 'XXXX'</simple>.   Use this inside camel "when" clause.

Comment: In java DSL, simple("${body.getSomething} == 'XXXX'")

Answer (score 0):

For reference, i was able to get it working. I added a custom filter class and checked the bean value within that. Also linked it within the choose option for routing.
My route is now:

```
   from("jms:myqueu")
    .choice()
        .when()
            .method(Exp.class,"checkfieldA")
            .json(JsonLibrary.Gson).
            .to("file://cc")
         .when() 
            .method(Exp.class,"checkfieldB")
            .json(JsonLibrary.Gson).
            .to("file://dd")
     .endChoice()
```

Here Exp is a normal class and checkfieldA and checkfieldB are two methods returning boolean values.

```
class Exp{

    public boolean checkfieldA(Message message){
      myobj obj = (myobj)message.getBody() // this is the object is put to queue. Need to cast to my object type .
        if(myobj.isFieldA()){
            return true;
           }
       }

    }
```

Comment: FYI, in the upcoming camel 2.18 you can leverage lambdas so you can do something like: when().body(MyType.class, b -> b.isFieldA())