# Set camel route based on timer or a count variable

Tags: java, apache-camel

I want to invoke another camel route based on a counter value or after certain time has passed whichever happens first. For example, if count has reached N before timer is invoked, I want to reset the timer and invoke the route. Similarly, if timer is invoked, reset the count and invoke the route.
I looked at this post -[Camel routing based on object value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39631153/camel-routing-based-on-object-value) 
But, how would I deal with Timer part?

I can do it in Java using ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor to cancel the task if count is reached and then invoke route in java. But, I was wondering if there is an easy way to do it with camel. I am new to Camel, so not aware about advanced functionality it can provide.

Answer (score 0):

Use a combination of Camel route, timer and content based router.
Set time and count in exchange property so they can be modified.

http://camel.apache.org/loop.html

http://camel.apache.org/timer.html

http://camel.apache.org/content-based-router.html